# Django - Set a default image on a model from a ForeignKey model

Tags: python, django, django-models

the problem I am having is as follows. I have two models as shown below, 'Profile' and 'Image', where each Image instance is connected by a ForeignKey to a single profile, so multiple Images will be linked to a single Profile. From this, I want to set a default image to the Profile by returning the first Image out of the set of related Images.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    ...
    def default_img(self):
        if self.p_image.count() > 0:
            return self.p_image[0]
        else:
            return False
class Image(models.Model):
    ...
    related_profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='p_image')
    img_path = models.ImageField(upload_to=profile_img,null=True,verbose_name='Image URL',height_field='h_field',width_field='w_field')
```

With the method that I am trying to do, Django returns the error '`'RelatedManager' object does not support indexing`' which is through the line '`return self.p_image[0]`', where I try to get the first object out of the set.

Any help on how to get this first object (without having to search through the entire set of Image objects)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index can be used in `Queryset` not in `RelatedManager`. Use

```
return self.p_image.all()[0]
```

> This will raise a IndexError if no objects match the given criteria. [Refer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets)